# W3C-Validator on Nginx

Tags: nginx, w3c-validation

any one know how to install  W3C-Validator on a RHEL machine with Nginx?

Answer (score 1):

1. install w3c validator http://validator.w3.org/source/ - there is a package available for RH
2. install nginx and configure its root